# How to optimise this query to retrieve a specific structure from two columns?

Tags: sql

Having two tables (Invoice,Contact), this query retrieves a list of contacts with the invoice total grouped by quarters of the year if the total amount of invoice subtotal + vat is greater than 3000.

Result structure example:

Contact name | Contact cif | Total (subtotal + vat) | Quarter

However, i think that this query is no optimised and could be shorter, so my question is,
is there a way to make it better?

Here is the SQL Fiddle and the query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29449/3

```
select 
  tc.id, 
  tc.name, 
  tc.cif, 
  sum(ti.subtotal) + sum(ti.vat) as Total, 
  extract(
    quarter 
    from 
      ti.date
  ) as quarter 
from 
  (
    select 
      tc.id, 
      tc.cif, 
      sum(ti.subtotal) + sum(ti.vat) as total 
    from 
      invoice ti 
      inner join contact tc on ti.contactId = tc.id 
    where 
      ti.isBlocked = FALSE 
      and cast(ti.date as Date) between '2020-01-01' 
      AND '2020-12-31' 
    group by 
      tc.id, 
      tc.cif 
    having 
      sum(ti.subtotal) + sum(ti.vat) > 3000 
    order by 
      tc.cif asc
  ) as source 
  inner join contact tc on tc.id = source.id 
  inner join invoice ti on ti.contactId = tc.id 
where 
  source.total > 3000 
  and cast(ti.date as Date) between '2020-01-01' 
  AND '2020-12-31' 
  and ti.isBlocked = FALSE 
group by 
  tc.id, 
  tc.cif, 
  tc.name, 
  quarter 
having 
  sum(ti.subtotal) + sum(ti.vat) > 0 
order by 
  tc.cif asc
```

Comment: By optimization do you mean, a shorter, more elegant query or a fast performing one?

Comment: Preferably a faster way but a shorter and elegant way would also be nice

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to writing subqueries as CTE's as they are easier to understand that way, and you may be causing a double read if you over-specify what you want in the subquery.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29449/35

```
WITH
  Source
  --Retrieve all Customers with NonBlocked Invoices with a Total of >3000
  AS
  (
    select
      tc.id
    from
      invoice ti
      inner join contact tc on ti.contactId = tc.id
    where 
      ti.isBlocked = FALSE
      and cast(ti.date as Date) between '2020-01-01' 
      AND '2020-12-31'
    group by 
      tc.id, 
      tc.cif
    having 
      sum(ti.subtotal) + sum(ti.vat) > 3000
  )
--Retrieve all Related Invoices
select
  tc.id,
  tc.name,
  tc.cif,
  sum(ti.subtotal) + sum(ti.vat) as Total,
  extract(
    quarter 
    from 
      ti.date
  ) as quarter
from
  source
  inner join contact tc on tc.id = source.id
  inner join invoice ti on ti.contactId = tc.id
where 
1=1
group by 
  tc.id, 
  tc.cif, 
  tc.name, 
  quarter
Having 
 sum(ti.subtotal) + sum(ti.vat) > 0 
order by 
  tc.cif asc
```